# Convert string of macro to macro

Tags: c, macros

How can a string like "EINVAL" be converted into EINVAL?

I have to convert a lot of macro string to their value, what can be done?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest method I can think of:

```
#include <errno.h>

if (!strcmp(str, "EINVAL"))
    value = EINVAL;
```

No preprocessor trick can convert the string literal to the corresponding symbol.

But you can use the preprocessor to simplify a sequence of such tests:

```
    value = 0;
#define conv(s)  do { if (!strcmp(str, #s)) value = s; } while (0)
    conv(EINVAL);
    conv(ENOMEM);
    conv(ERANGE);
    conv(EINTR);
#undef conv
```

A usual, be careful with the preprocessor...

Comment: There is no general way to do this? I have to do it for all the macro I want?

Comment: @anothertest Yes, in C there's no other option.

Comment: @anothertest: I modified the answer for a general method to generate such code.